# Connect to Oracle DB server remotely

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, sql

I have Oracle 9i database installed on machine connected to the Internet behind NAT and the Oracle database server is listening on default port 1521.

When I connect over LAN to the database server it has worked perfectly.

When I did port forwarding on port 1521 to the private IP address in my TP-Link router to allow the Oracle client machine to connect to the Oracle database server over that public IP it isn't working properly.

It's successful on `canyouseeme.org` but when I use this command:

> SQL>connect username/password@GLOBAL_IP/service_name Error: ORA_12170:
>   TNS : Connect timeout occurred .

*Note: when i try to connect to oracle DB server using Teamviewer vpn also it works and connected.*

So how can I deal with this?

Comment: I have attempted to fix your grammar but I feel that a lot of context is still missing. Please rollback my edits if you feel I have gone too far.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have correctly set the alias with the public address on your client side, which is most often done by editing `tnsnames.ora` file. I guess it's not needed to remind you this is very inappropriate solution even for fun or testing purposes and for security reasons you should always use VPN.